# Dovecot imap-login: confusing error? message

Tags: dovecot, imap

I am busy setting up a mailserver with postfix, dovecot and mariadb on a Debian 9 system.

Receiving mail fails on port 993 as result of a time-out with this message in/var/log/dovecot.log:

```
imap-login: Info: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 117 secs): user=<>, rip=1.2.3.4, lip=2.3.4.5, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() syscall failed: Success, session=<+tax6Y97OpplYc73>
```

I am confused by the words accept, failed and Success.
Obviously something failed, because imap on 993 timed-out.
Could the message indicate the cause of the failure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by checking that the SSL CERT is in order, installed at the correct location and has the correct file owner and mode. 644 for the certificate and 600 for the private key

Then test it manually, using: `openssl s_client -connect mailserver.example.com:993 -crlf`

You should see the certificates in clear text, and a line at the end: `* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot ready.`

Then you know that the system is ready to accept the AUTH command.

**Edit**

/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf :  check the settings for `ssl_ca, ssl_cert and ssl_key`

Answer (score 3):

The openssl command as mentioned by Ingvar, finally lead me to overcome the `accept,failed, succes` line in `/var/log/dovecot.log`

The problem was caused by an ambiguous character (#) in the user password in order to execute mysql queries on the mailserver.
After issueing Ingvar's `openssl s_client -connect mailserver.example.com:993 -crlf` suggestion, I encountered a line that login problem:

```
Warning: Configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext line 72: Ambiguous '#' character in line, treating it as comment. Add a space before it to remove this warning
```

I resetted the password for mysql and the dovecot.log now lacks the confusing line!

Comment: A char in the password? Are you storing cleartext passwords?

Comment: Yes only to connect to as mysql low privileged user. (Has only SELECT permission)